# Should "the number of college students going overseas" use "who go" instead?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which of the following sentences sound more natural?

- I'm surprised at the number of college students **going** overseas.
- I'm surprised at the number of college students **who go** overseas.

Comment: Both are correct, but _who_ _go_ is not equal to _going_. The first states a fact and implies _recurrence_ (...who go overseas, say, every year). _going_, here, can mean the same as _who_ _go_ and can also be indicative of a single  _incident_ (...going overseas this year). I'm not a native speaker, so you'd better take my words with a grain of salt :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sound equally natural.

However, they express slightly different notions.

The first is in the **present continuative**, so it can be used for when there are students currently going overseas, for example, if you're standing at a pier watching a boat leave the harbour, or if you're speaking about a news report which mentions students going overseas around this time.

The second is in the **simple present** which you would use to express a habit, for example, when speaking of students who go overseas frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I think both of them are correct.

The second sentence is a nominal clause which can be rewritten as the following sentence:

- I'm surprised at the number of college students (who are) going overseas.

Then we could omit the **who** and **are**, because the subject **who** just is the repetition of **students** and the linking verb **are** has no practical significance. Then you can find the result of Reduced Adjective Clauses is as same as 
your first sentence.

Furthermore, **going** is a present participle meaning that the thing is in process or happening. So it have a little difference between the two sentences.

If you want to present the student ready to go overseas , you can use the infinitive as following:

- I'm surprised at the number of college students to go overseas.

You could think it's a another Reduced Adjective Clause:

- I'm surprised at the number of college students (who will / are going to) go overseas.